Linking a token to a user
I'm using wso2 Identity Server as a central IAM and we registered a web app as an app client. But during security test, we noticed that The bearer generated when a user logs in is not linked to his session.
Any valid bearer can be used to make a request even unauthorized to the original user.
How to configure wso2 IS in order the bearer be unique and linked to a user?
Thank very much.
The developpers tried to resolve the trouble but without any success
